# Virtual Box: always receive keyboard input from host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox on Windows 7 to run Ubuntu. I would like to have the VM *receive input from windows* without pressing the host key (R-Ctrl). When I switch to the VM window from Windows, it looks like this,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmXhz.png]

The green down arrow indicating that input from windows isn't accepted. After pressing the Host key, the arrow grays out,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSi5j.png]

How can I make it so the arrow is always grayed out, even after switching between VM and other Windows programs (as I don't want to press R-Ctrl every time I switch back to the VM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover over the green/gray arrow with the mouse pointer, you should see that green actually indicates that input is captured, and that gray is not: the opposite of what you said.

For a while now, Linux on VirtualBox will auto-capture, once the window gets focus by clicking on it or Alt-Tabbing to it. (I tried this just now with Ubuntu 12.04 on VirtualBox 4.2)

Note that even if you Right-Ctrl to release capture (and the arrow is gray), most keystrokes will still go to the window as long as it maintains focus. The notable exceptions are those like Alt-Tab (try it with both the arrow green and gray).

EDIT: can you give an example of when "the VM receives input from Windows"? In any case, does turning off auto-capture -- in the main Manager Window, ["File" -> "Preferences" -> "Input" -> "Auto-capture keyboard"](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#specialcharacters), and don't forget to click OK -- do what you want?

Comment: Ken, I would like to receive input from windows when in the VM-linux window, so I want the arrow to always be gray and never auto-capture (see edit in my post)

Comment: Great, yes that is exactly what I was looking for! Will upvote when I get more reputation

Comment: that 'auto capture keyboard' option doesn't seem to work w/ a centos image. it does with ubuntu server however...quite strange